# Saving images to my own directory? image to fit Screen Size?

Tags: android, imageview, wallpaper

i implementing a wallpaper app. it has a lot of images of about 100.

1) i want to save  those images in gallery with a seperate folder.
2) when set as wallpaper the size the image Zooms ,how to fit to screen size?

i used

```
 MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle     ,yourDescription);
```

it stores in a folder named camera, but i need my own directoy name.

i tried many things , many searches for fitting the image to screen size

i used display metrics like

```
Bitmap bmap2 =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.paper)); 


DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmap2, width, height, true); 

WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this); 
try {
 wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
 } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

and some other  dispaly metrics  but none worked..
as i am having many images i used a switch case ,

i am using a horizontal scroll view where images are present when a image is clicked here.
it goes to the main view and below it i have a set wallpaper button..!!

my code...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
    ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);

    ImageView image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    ImageView image8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
    ImageView image9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
```

display is the main image view 
image1 , image2 .... are images in horizontal scroll view...!!

i 've used a switch case for setting the horizontzal view images to main image view ..

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

     case R.id.imageView11:
        wallpaper.setEnabled(true);

        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.w1);
        tophone = R.drawable.w1;

        break;
    case R.id.imageView2:
        wallpaper.setEnabled(true);

        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.w2);
        tophone = R.drawable.w2;

        break;
    case R.id.imageView3:
        wallpaper.setEnabled(true);
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.w3);
        tophone = R.drawable.w3;

        break;
```

and when set wall paper is clicked.!

```
case R.id.button1:

        img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(
                tophone));
        try {
            WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                    .setBitmap(img);
            Toast showtoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            showtoast.show();
            break;

        } catch (Exception m) {

        }
        img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(
                tophone));
        try {
            WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                    .setBitmap(img);
            Toast showtoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            showtoast.show();
            break;

        } catch (Exception m) {

        }
```

can anyone please help me..
i 've been trying since a week for these 2 solutions.